# Llenar una lista en Python con for e if elif

Tags: python, lista

tengo una lista en Python, que es A = [2,1,0,2,3,4,4,3,5,7], y quiero generar otra lista, B, donde el primer elemento sea igual al primer elemente de A.

Para los siguientes elementos de B, éstos dependerán de si los elementos de A cumplen un condición o no.

Tengo el siguiente código de prueba:

```
A=[2,1,0,2,3,4,4,3,5,7]

B = []
for i in A:
    if(i == A[0]):
        B.append(i)
    elif(i != A[0]):
        if(i < i-1):
        B.append(i+1)
    else: (B.append(i))
```

pero al hacerlo correr el resultado que obtengo para B es el mismo elemento A.

Lo que quiero conseguir es que la primera posición de B sea igual a la primera posición de A; para las otras posiciones de B, el resultado va a depender de cómo se comporte el valor de A con respecto al valor anterior.

Espero puedan ayudarme al respecto.

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `if (i < i - 1)`? `i` siempre será mayor que `i - 1` y la condición nunca se cumplirá..

Comment: i está en A, y en A para algunas posiciones, el valor es menor al anterior.
En este caso i hace referencia al valor y no a la posición.

Comment: esta aquí  if(i < i-1): siembre va a ser menor que i por lo que salta al else final osea al numero del valor de A

Comment: `i` nunca puede ser menor que `i-1`, por lo que la condición del `if`en el el `elif` nunca se va a cumplir. Revisa bien lo que quieres hacer porque ahí lo que hace siempre es, en la primera iteración añadir el valor 0 y, en la del resto, añadir cada elemento `i` de la lista de A.


Edit: Estoy viendo que lo que quieres es comprobar el valor anterior de la lista.. Ahí, o haces la comparación con `A[i - 1]` o con `B[i - 1]`. Porque así sí puedes comprobar el valor anterior y, en esos casos, sí puede ser menor que `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En pro de la legibilidad del código, es recomendable reducir el número
de condiciones(if, elif, else).

El problema principal de tu script se reduce a una cuestión matemática, ya que
i siempre será mayor que i-1.

Te propongo el siguiente código:

```
A=[2,1,0,2,3,4,4,3,5,7]

B=A[:1]

for i in A[1:]:
    if i < 3:
        B.append(i+1)
        continue
    B.append(i)
```

Recuerda el Zen de Python: Simple es mejor que complejo. Plano es mejor que anidado.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta carser. Voy a revisar lo que comentas y así poder aprender/entender de mejor manera Python.

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias cosas erróneas o mejorables en tu código.

El error más grave es suponer que `i-1` te va a dar el elemento anterior. Si estás por ejemplo en el segundo elemento que vale 1, entonces `i` será 1, por lo que `i-1` será 0 y no el elemento anterior.

Otro error es hacer la comparación `if i==A[0]` para determinar si estás o no estás en el primer elemento. Esto en realidad está comparando `i` con 2 (pues `A[0]` vale 2), y por tanto será cierto para cualquiera de los casos en que `i` valga 2 (y hay otro 2 en la lista) y no sólo cuando estemos ante el primer elemento.

Para resolver tu problema necesitas iterar sobre los *índices* del array, en lugar de hacerlo sobre los valores. Es decir, necesitas que `i` vaya tomando los valores 0, 1, 2, 3, ... en lugar de 2, 1, 0, 2, 3. De ese modo puedes acceder a `A[i]` para obtener el valor del elemento actual y a `A[i-1]` para obtener el valor del elemento anterior.

Para iterar por una serie de enteros consecutivos (0, 1, 2, 3, ...) se usa `range()`. En tu código también usas `i+1` y voy a suponer que lo que necesitas ahí es también el elemento siguiente de la lista (y no el elemento actual incrementado en una unidad).

Quedaría entonces así:

```
A=[2,1,0,2,3,4,4,3,5,7]

B = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    if i == 0:
        B.append(A[i])
    else:
        if  A[i] < A[i-1]:
           B.append(A[i+1])
        else: 
           B.append(A[i])
```

No obstante ese código puede producir errores en tiempo de ejecución si el último elemento de la lista cumple ser menor que el anterior (no es el caso en la lista que pones de ejemplo, pero podría suceder). En ese caso tienes puesto que se añada a `B` el elemento siguiente, pero si estamos en el último ya no habrá elemento siguiente y tendrás un error. Deberías aclarar qué habría que hacer en ese caso.

Por otro lado el código se simplifica un poco si en vez de iterar desde i=0 lo haces desde i=1. Así ya no tienes que andar comprobando si estás o no en el primer elemento. Ese primer elemento puedes copiarlo antes de entrar al bucle. Quedaría entonces así:

```
A=[2,1,0,2,3,4,4,3,5,7]

B = [A[0]]
for i in range(1, len(A)):
    if  A[i] < A[i-1]:
       B.append(A[i+1])
    else: 
       B.append(A[i])
```

Comment: Abulafia, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
Me queda mucho más claro el código.
La verdad yo uso R en general para programar pero ahora estoy probando con Python, y hay cosas que pensaba se hacían se manera distinta, pero al parecer es bien similar.
Voy a revisar el código que enviaste y modificarlo lo necesario para ver si logro lo que necesito.
De verdad muchas gracias.